# Tomcat not handling 500 internal server code thrown by external service

Tags: java, tomcat, redis

I have my application deployed on Tomcat and also it connects to Redis server for caching . The issue that I am facing is , when the Redis server goes down/times out for whatever reason , I see 500 internal server error on application web page with all those error trace. There is a custom error page configured in web.xml in my application which should be displayed when 500 error code is there . 
I also tried putting a default sample error page in the tomcat/conf folder where web.xml sits and also configured the mapping for it in web.xml . Still no luck . Can anyone please suggest .

Mapping :-

```
 <error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/sample.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

To reproduce and test in local , after starting application on tomcat ,I will shutdown the redis-server.Now, when I try to traverse on the web page it displays 500 internal server erroor with redis connection issues but in tomcat logs doesn't increase and nothing related to redis error and 500 code in the logs .

Some more info on this : when the exception happens , the tiles return the correct view name which is my custom error page view , but then it is being taken over by some background exception manager and tomcat loosed control over it:-

```
catalina-utility-1:org.apache.cataline.core.standardcontext.backgroundprocess Exception processing manager[RedissonSessionManager][standardhost:localhost][standardcontext:/applicationname]
```

After this there redisson related error and on web page it's same 500 internal server error with all error messages.

Comment: The mapping only helps if your Tomcat would return a `500` so I would validate if it indeed passes the error on or if he processes the error by himself turning it into something else

Comment: @Smutje - Even I am confused with this ,I also suspect that the error is not being received by Tomcat but why and how to fix this ? I canot display those error stact trace to user

Comment: It is your code, you should be able to trace the request and how it is handled.

Comment: The application keeps on writing some payloads in Redis-server  for caching , but as soon as I stop the redis-server in local , there is no log output in  tomcat but 500 internal server error page gets displayed on web. Since there is not log output ,I am not able to understand this, Posted this to know if someone has faced it and aware of it already

Comment: @Smutje I have added some more information .Please have a look once